# DataStructure file and file with inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a `.sql` file with the datastructure and one with the inserts.

How can I import the to Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Studio? If anyone interest here is the file for inserts and for datastructure.

If you can't download the file you can find the content of datastructure [here](http://pastebin.com/R9UBF1YA) and for inserts [here](http://pastebin.com/Ebmv32jj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files had contained sql code that you could run in SMSS you would use `file->open->file` (or `ctrl+o`) to open the file.

Your files however are MySQL dumps and contain code that MS SQL won't understand that you need to fix. Using the reference documentation it should be easy to alter the structure-file so that it works. In the insert-file you probably only need to remove the backticks.

Comment: thank you very much for your kid answer. I tried the File --> Open --> File because the initial file .sql I have is 700MB. I tried to import it with the classic way but it gives me always this message Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' even if I have all other programms closed. So I used this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vt7-QHyOxQA to spilt the file into pieces and it give a datastructure file an many files with inserts.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Because I am not familiar with sql please could you explain me what is the backticks and the reference documentation for you structure-file. If it is possible could you give me an example for this? Thank you very much if you have time to help me.

Comment: The reference documentation is the manual/documentation that comes with MSSQL Server, it describes the valid syntax for the different commands used and will help you determine what you need to remove (or comment out which it looks like you've done in the structure file you linked). The backticks are used in MySQL to enclose table (and other object) names and can be seen in the ` `INSERT INTO `auth_permission` ` statement for instance. As they are used in the markup in the comments I can't show them here, but you'll see them around the `auth_permission` for instance.

Comment: So as I can understand for the backticks the only thing I have to make is into the insert file remove the whole insert query which starts with ` INSERT INTO auth_permission` right?

Comment: @user3456789 Yes I think that is the only change you have to do in the insert file. Remove all backticks and it should be fine.